# Метод api отрабатывает, но не сохраняет данные Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, api

Написал метод, который сохранят данные в бд.

- Через **postman** проверил: данные уходят и приходят.
- Через `dd()` просмотрел новая коллекция модели создается.
- Попробовал через `DB::table()`.

Данные уходят и приходят все окей. 
Но в бд не сохраняются.

- На скринах как раз показаны ответы postman(при добавлении) и ответ dd(), когда я смотрел, что SQL код выполняется.
- Ошибок приложение не выдает.
- Также перезагружал страницу phpmyadmin, данных нет.
- Переписал с нулю контроллер, но данные не поступают.
- Проверил .env файл, все окей.

При этом:

- Другие маршруты работают.
- Также работает маршрут, где я использую модель, которая есть в нерабочем.
- Делал несколько тестов в postman`e id у элементов меняются, но так и не выводятся при запросе get и в phpmyadmin

[image: Проверил через dd() какие SQL запросы идут]
[image: Проверил через postman и получил положительный ответ]

Мой контроллер

```
    public function store(SemanticsRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        // DB::enableQueryLog();

        $newGroup = Group::create([
            'title' => $request->group,
        ]);

        $newSubgroup = $newGroup->subgroups()->create([
            'title' => $request->subgroup,
        ]);

        foreach ($request->phrases as $item) {

            $newSubgroup->phrases()->create([
                'phrase' => $item['phrase'],
            ]);

        }

        // dd(DB::getQueryLog());

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {

        /**
         * Откат транзакции, если произошла ошибка
         */
        DB::rollback();


        return $this->sendError('Конфликт при добавлении данных в базу данных', 409);
    }

    return $this->sendResponse(new SubGroupResource($newSubgroup), 'Запрос успешно выполнен.');

}
```

В модели указаны с какими полями я работаю, также для теста указал принудительно с какой таблицей необходимо работать.

Уже несколько дней не могу понять причину, почему не сохраняются данные, но id и положительный запрос идёт от api.

Помогите пожалуйста, если сталкивались с этим

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1):

Прочтите о том как работают транзакции. Вы их начинаете и всё. Но не делаете итоговый коммит чтобы применить изменения в рамках открытой транзакции.

Решение проблемы:

```
DB::commit();
```